# Short story (read in the 80s) where traffic speed was goverment's top priority

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Going slow (under 70?) was an offense but you were paint balled from the air and fined later.

Massive pileups were removed by helicopter electro-magnets to keep things moving.

At the end of the story an iconic NYC skyscraper (maybe Empire State Building) is demolished just so they can straighten a road and reduce pileups.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you recall if you read this in an anthology or a magazine?

Comment: oh darn - I read this story too and I've remembered it off and on for years - typically wishing I had the *cop's paintball gun and powers*.  Usually when behind another car I'd like to use it on. IIRC when you were paint-balled from the air (cop helicopter) your car was confiscated when you got off the expressway and it was destroyed.  That's what I'd really like to have the power of.  But can't remember anything else about the story (title, author).  Hope you get an answer here!

Comment: That's it!  Traffic Problem by William Earls. :-) I've asked many people over the years and thought "Why Not Here". Many thanks.

Comment: Thanks for this, I don't hear about much utopian fiction

Comment: @davidbak there was a comedian, I think it was Gallagher but I can't find any references, who had a similar idea.  He called it "dummy darts", you see a car doing something stupid and you hit it with a dummy dart.  If a car collects enough darts the cops automatically give you a ticket.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is *[Traffic Problem](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?189697)* by William Earls.  You can read it at the Luminist Archive here in the [October 1970 Galaxy Magazine](http://www.luminist.org/archives/SF/GAL.htm).

It ends

> The Destruction team had the top ten floors off the Empire State Building and a corner cut off the fortieth floor with a lane of traffic whipping through it.

Comment: seems like an accurate representation of how things were going at the time. We demolished huge areas of our cities to "improve traffic flow". I've seen comparisons of Houston after the car, to Hiroshima after the atom bomb, and they do not look terribly different from each other (cherry-picked photos, of course)

Comment: There were actually plans for an elevated expressway from the Lincoln Tunnel to the Queens Midtown Tunnel, roughly around 30th street. This is why the LIE is I-495 and the NJ approach to the Lincoln Tunnel is NJ-495; the whole thing was supposed to be a spur of I-95 from Weehawken to Suffolk County. On the one hand, they would have had to destroy a lot of buildings; on the other hand, millions of people out on Long Island would have less of a bottleneck between them and the rest of the country.